# logging in to a website using python

Tags: python, urllib

What's wrong in this code? I tried to logging into ISP client page using Python 3.4 and got same html page back.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from http import cookiejar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.exampe.com/login.php"
name = "username"
passw = "password"

def Login():
    cj = cookiejar.CookieJar()
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
    redirect =urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    values = {'unam' : name, 'pass' : passw}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = data.encode('utf-8')
    login = urllib.request.Request(url,binary_data,headers)
    login_response = opener.open(login)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_response.read(),'lxml')
    print(soup)

Login()
```

Comment: There is a lot of reasons why it may not works. You should investigate more your ISP page and check if there aren't some hidden fields or other protection against this way to login.

Comment: its not only for ISP page but also for other web pages also .

Comment: Sorry, but much more info is need to help you. Maybe inspect better the page.

Comment: Login pages may have anything as name of fieds for user and password. They may even have special field against Cross Site Request Forgery. All that means that a login procedure **must** be adapted for each login page.

Comment: take example as Facebook after i execute this program i am getting same html page back .....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        import urllib.request
        import urllib.parse
        from http import cookiejar
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        login = 'user'
        password = 'password''
        cook = 'mfp.cookies'
        url = "https://example/login.php"
        cj = cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar(cook)
        opener=urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
        urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(),urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
        urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'Wink]
        values = {'uname' : login,'upass' : password,'login' : 'Login'}
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
        binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
        s = opener.open(url,binary_data)
        main = opener.open('http://example.com/page/1/index.php')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(main.read(),'lxml')

        cj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

`values = {'unam' : name, 'pass' : passw}` here it is assumed that the form element names are `unam` and `pass` which varies from site to site. For example if you are trying to login to Facebook, then the field names are `email` and `pass`. Then the line must be modified as
`values = {'email' : name, 'pass' : passw}`

Inspect the element from the webpage you need to login to determine the names and use them as such.

Comment: getting same html page back